# Multi dimension linear interpolation vba

Tags: vba, dynamic, multidimensional-array, linear-interpolation

I am trying to write the VBA code for a multi-dimension linear interpolation and I would really appreciate your help as I am not sure where to start.

I have a set of variables, let s call them X,Y,Z in this example but the number of variables will vary in the final macro.
Each variable can take a number of different values. So in this example

X can be 1,2,

Y can be 10,20,30

Z can be 100,200,300,400

This gives me 2*3*4 = 24 possible scenarios. Each  scenario correspond to a value F(x,y,z).

This gives me a grid that looks like that
[combination grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epCrS.png)

Now for a given set of values of X,Y,Z, say (1.5,21,390) 
I would like to linearly interpolate in each dimension to get the approximation value of f(1.5,21,390) based on the grid above.

I would use the value of f in 2^3=8 scenarios (shown below)to calculate that approximated value.
[Scenario used for linear interpolations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJxDZ.png)
For each scenario, I get a weight ( which is the product of the weights obtained by linear interpolation in each dimension) and the approximate value I am looking for is the weighted average the values of f in each scenario.

So the weight of the first scenario would be 0.5*0.9*0.1 etc

All the variables will be dynamic ( the number of variables and the number of values each variable can take will vary)

I would really appreciate any help or tip as to how to achieve the expected results.

Thank you very much

Comment: Interesting question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation is a starting point. There are several different methods of multivariate interpolation listed there, so you would have to choose which method of interpolation is appropriate to your application before you start coding it.

Comment: Hi @CustodianOfCode, thanks for your reply. 
I am looking to do the linear interpolation described here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation 
but generalised in N dimension.  Wiki does not have a page for the Ndimension case, but I think that this should be possible (?) on a N-dimensional regular grid.